# Setting up google speech to text on google cloud - Error: spawn SoX ENOENT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-speech, sox

I've followed a bunch of tutorials on Google's speech to text, and have it all working fine locally. My setup is using websockets (socket.io) to communicate between a client Angular app and a node/express backend that does the server-side call to the speech API. I am using `streaming-recognize` ( https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize ) to read mic stream and return results.

**This works fully locally**, but I have an issue when running it on the `gcloud app deploy` instance in that I haven't actually installed the `SoX` dependency (done locally via `brew install sox` . This is a requirement for their example of setting up the mic stream.

I think I need to set up a virtual machine instance which I can provision with SoX, but also feel this seems a bit overkill - is there an alternative? I did try to manually parse and send the mic data stream as Uint8Array/ArrayBuffer chunkns with some success, but not much. I also read some hypothesis about non-SoX approaches to processing user mic stream, but to no avail. Eg with recordrtc.

The question is - what do I need to do to get this working in gcloud? Set up a vm instance, install sox, and use that? Or is there a SoX-free way to get this running?
Guidance welcomed!

Here's the server error I get on gcloud - it seems to me because it has not got SoX on its path:

```
Error: spawn sox ENOENT      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
  Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    errno: 'ENOENT',
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'spawn sox',
    path: 'sox',
    spawnargs: [
      '--default-device',
      '--no-show-progress',
      '--rate',
      16000,
      '--channels',
      1,
      '--encoding',
      'signed-integer',
      '--bits',
      '16',
      '--type',
      'wav',
      '-'
    ]
  }
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! <APPNAME>@0.0.0 start:prod: `node server.js;`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the <APPNAME>@0.0.0 start:prod script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-30T22_12_35_041Z-debug.log
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! <APPNAME>@0.0.0 start: `npm run start:prod`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the <APPNAME>@0.0.0 start script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-30T22_12_35_074Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set up Google Speech to Text and you want to deploy it on Google App Engine ( gcloud app deploy ).

However Google Speech to Text has a [Sox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sox) dependency and this required the Sox CLI to be installed in the Operating System.

So you will need to use App Engine Flexible environment with a Custom Runtime. In the Dockerfile, you can specify to install the SOX CLI.

I was able to successfully deploy an App Engine Flex app that consumes Speech to Text API using the steps provided in the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart) and the sample code from the [nodejs-speech repository](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/tree/master/samples). Please have a look into it.

************** UPDATE **************

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs

# Working directory is where files are stored, npm is installed, and the application is launched
WORKDIR /app

# Copy application to the /app directory.
# Add only the package.json before running 'npm install' so 'npm install' is not run if there are only code changes, no package changes
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN apt-get update
RUN  apt-get install -y sox
RUN npm install
COPY . /app

# Expose port so when the container is launched you can curl/see it.
EXPOSE 8080

# The command to execute when Docker image launches.
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Please try the above Dockerfile and adapt it to your needs, it's an example of how to install sox.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direction! looks very promising. I have fone some research and tried to set it up following this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/tree/master/nginx 
I am having a bit of difficulty getting it going - do you have an example of a Dockerfile I could use to get my Flexible env  running, with SoX installed?

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look into it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It's sorted all the errors I had up to this point - now getting a somewhat cryptic error `sox has exited with error code 2.` . No other error above or below this when tailing the `gcloud app logs tail` . Have had a google but can't spot anything - thought I'd ask here incase you saw similar. This all works locally; maybe missing an install?

Comment: Ah, i think the sox error code is a red herring... maybe my google creds haven't authorised. Looking now.

Comment: My error is in the bit where i try to access the mic stream. Can anyone think of anything that may be missing? something obvious no doubt :(  - it works locally.

Code in question:

```
const recorder = require('node-record-lpcm16');
recorder
    .record({
      sampleRateHertz: 16000,
      threshold: 0,
      verbose: false,
      recordProgram: 'rec',
      silence: '10.0',
    })
    .stream()
    .on('error', (error) => console.log('ERROR with recorder.record', error))
    .pipe(recognizeStream);
```

output:
`ERROR with record.record sox has exited with error code 2.`

Comment: cheers, realised your Dockerfile was the fix so have accepted it, and made a new question with the subsequent error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100476/google-speech-to-text-node-record-lpcm16-stream-error . Thanks again!